# php change structure of object / json

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am working with laravel and angular and I am trying to add some charts, now I need to get data in a specific structure for the chart plugin, currently my api returns a json like this one below:

```
"data": {
    "enero": {
      "value": 50
    },
    "febrero": {
      "value": 130
    },
    "marzo": {
      "value": 220
    },
    "abril": {
      "value": 440
    },
    "mayo": {
      "value": 700
    },
    "junio": null,
    "julio": null,
    "agosto": null,
    "septiembre": null,
    "octubre": null,
    "noviembre": null,
    "diciembre": null
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
"data": [
            {
                "value": "50"
            },
            {
                "value": "130"
            },
            {
                "value": "220"
            },
            {
                "value": "440"
            },
            {
                "value": "700"
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "value": null
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Have you tried something till yet?

Comment: show the code, generating that json

Comment: Ok, so...what's your question? [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how can I do that?, I am new in php

Comment: @RubenMoralesFelix Hope my post will give you the exact output you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `array_map` to gather required ouput.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787333)

```
<?php

$string='{"data": {
    "enero": {
      "value": 50
    },
    "febrero": {
      "value": 130
    },
    "marzo": {
      "value": 220
    },
    "abril": {
      "value": 440
    },
    "mayo": {
      "value": 700
    },
    "junio": null,
    "julio": null,
    "agosto": null,
    "septiembre": null,
    "octubre": null,
    "noviembre": null,
    "diciembre": null
}
}';
$result=array_map(function($value){
    return is_array($value) ? array("value"=>$value["value"]) : array("value"=>$value);
}, json_decode($string,true)["data"]);
$newResult["data"]=array_values($result);
echo json_encode($newResult,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 50
        },
        {
            "value": 130
        },
        {
            "value": 220
        },
        {
            "value": 440
        },
        {
            "value": 700
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "value": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null coalesce to null when trying to access `value` values in a loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3iZ08))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json)->data as $v) {
    $result['data'][]['value'] = $v->value ?? null;
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = []; // new array
foreach($oldArray['data'] as $key => $value){
  $data['data'][]['value'] = $value['value'];
}
```

Comment: This answer generates warnings and should not be used. https://3v4l.org/bS4TR